# Any way for React in a popup to communicate with parent window?

Tags: reactjs

I've got an OAuth process that pops up a window, but when I log in, the redirect to the OAuth callback page happens within the popup rather than the parent window (`window.opener`). This might be a bit hacky, but I'd like a way for the popup window to tell the parent "we're authorized!"

This actually works:

```
OAuthCallback = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'OAuthCallback',

  render() {
    window.opener.console.log('hello parent window');

    return (
      <div>
        Hi, OAuth is process is done.
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

But I'm wondering if there's some way I can have the popup window tell the parent window to call a prop function, e.g. `this.props.oauthSucceeded()`.

Comment: I wrote this library that deals with the popup and everything: https://github.com/kgoedecke/react-oauth-popup

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you are unable to establish any parent-child or sibling relationship between the components, React recommends setting up an event system.

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

see https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Have a look at `window.postMessage` for cross window communication (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: This is beyond event systems though, I'm talking about a popup window accessing a parent window's components, which really are in a totally different set of states.

Comment: It's still possible to communicate thus setup event listeners cross window, edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Eelke's suggestion was spot on.

I used `window.postMessage()` in the child window, then `window.close()`, then added a `window.addEventListener('message', function(){})` in the `componentDidMount` method of of main/master component.

Check out https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html for more information!

Comment: better to use `window.opener.postMessage()`, `window.postMessage()` is not working

Answer (score 0):

I had a unique situation where I had to work on an iframed react popup from an asp.net application. I had to provide a `x` button to close the popup by calling a `closePopup` method in the parent asp.net in addition to other ways to close it. I used `window.parent`. Below is how I used it.

```
if (window && window.parent) {
    window.parent.closePopup();
}
```